Why am I not able to deploy my contract using Hardhat?
const hre = require("hardhat");
const { ethers } = hre; // Ensure ethers is imported correctly
const fs = require("fs");

const COORDINATOR = "0x343300b5d84D444B2ADc9116FEF1bED02BE49Cf2";
const KEY_HASH = "0x816bedba8a50b294e5cbd47842baf240c2385f2eaf719edbd4f250a137a8c899";
const SUBSCRIPTION_ID = "11444315466576644620310837629580433434095437229645669214146591973758562356015";
const BET_TOKEN_ADDRESS = "0x9F798fcCf01FeB0e88607505629CaB6B9DC14Be2";

async function main() {
  const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();

  // Check deployer's balance in MATIC
  const balance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(deployer.address);
  console.log(`Deployer balance: ${ethers.utils.formatEther(balance)} MATIC`);

  // Ensure deployer has at least 4 MATIC
  if (balance.lt(ethers.utils.parseEther("4"))) {
    console.error("Insufficient funds. Please ensure the deployer has at least 4 MATIC");
    process.exit(1);
  }

  // Deploy CoinFlip contract
  const CoinFlip = await ethers.getContractFactory("CoinFlip");
  console.log("Deploying CoinFlip...");
  const coinFlip = await CoinFlip.deploy(COORDINATOR, KEY_HASH, SUBSCRIPTION_ID, BET_TOKEN_ADDRESS);
  await coinFlip.deployed();
  const coinFlipAddress = coinFlip.address; // Use the address property directly

  console.log("\nCoinFlip deployed to: ", coinFlipAddress);

  // Send 1 MATIC to the deployed contract for operational purposes
  const tx = {
    to: coinFlipAddress,
    value: ethers.utils.parseEther("1")
  };

  console.log("\nSending 1 MATIC to the deployed contract for operational purposes...");
  try {
    const txResponse = await deployer.sendTransaction(tx);
    await txResponse.wait();
    console.log("1 MATIC has been sent to the contract.");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error sending MATIC to the contract:", error.message);
    process.exit(1);
  }

  // Get and log CoinFlip ABI
  const coinFlipABI = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./artifacts/contracts/CoinFlip.sol/CoinFlip.json", "utf8"));
  const abi = JSON.stringify(coinFlipABI.abi);
  console.log("\nCoinFlip ABI:");
  console.log(abi);

  console.log("\nNote: All betting transactions will be done using the ERC20 token at address:", BET_TOKEN_ADDRESS);
}

main().catch((error) => {
  console.error("Deployment failed:", error.message);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});

When I try to deploy, I get an error:
Deployment failed: (0 , ethers_1.getAddress) is not a function
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

I'm using ethersv5.7.2 but the issue still persists.
I'm pretty sure the error is somewhere here but I can't seem to figure out what it is.

can you update ethers to v6
